# Substituting in Code Descriptions for Coded Variables in R

Tags: r

Code Description table:

```
    Procedure   X1    X2  X3  Desc
1   3852        002   0   0   Brain
2   3853        003   0   0   Heart
3   3854        004   0   0   Skin
4   3876        005   0   0   Throat
```

Table with just the code as well as frequencies of that code:

```
    Procedure   Freq
1   3852        22
2   3853        3
```

I would like to make the table like this:

```
    Procedure   Freq
1   Brain       22
2   Heart       3
```

I have tried merging on the procedure variable but it did not work.  the merge command i used was:

total <- data.frame(merge(code description table, frequencies, by="Procedure"))

the 2 table names were replaced by the real ones i had to use for the analysis.  Thank you for the help!

```
    Procedures  2012    2011    2010    2009
1   PatientIDs  427     419     399     399
2   ClaimIDs    420     407     389     391
3   3852        0       0       0       20
4   3853        0       0       0       8
5   3854        0       0       0       10

X1  Procedures  X2  X3          Desc                        X4
2   0002        V26 ICD9Proc    THER ULTRASOUND OF HEART    THER ULTRASOUND OF 
3   0003        V26 ICD9Proc    THER ULT PERIPHERAL VES     THER ULT PERIPHERAL 
4   0009        V26 ICD9Proc    OTHER THERAPEUTIC ULTSND    OTHER THERAPEUTIC
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your tables are in two data.frames `df1` and `df2`,

```
both<-merge(df1,df2)
both <- both[,c("Desc", "Freq")]
colnames(both)[1] <- "Procedure"
```

Comment: I do not believe that works.  It says i need a by variable so i put in my procedure.  I am not sure if that is the correct approach.  Thank you once again for your help.  Sorry i am very new to R

Comment: when i do merge them i get many more rows in the final dataset than there is in the table with the procedures and frequencies.

Comment: Do you have more columns than you're showing us above? Can you `dput` a few rows of your data?

Comment: I added some of the real data.  The patientids and claimids are just frequencies for those.  I have the matching procedure codes for the procedures in the first table.  I realized that there are different descriptions for the same procedure code.  I just want to be able to get maybe the first description in there and ignore the ones after.  thanks for the help again!

Answer (score 0):

If the first table is `df1` and assuming there is only 1 "Desc" for each "Procedure":

```
desc_map <- unique(df1[c('Procedure', 'Desc')])
```

Assuming the second table is `df2`:

```
df2_merged <- merge(df2, desc_map, by = 'Procedure')
```

Keep the columns you want:

```
df_final <- df2_merged[c('Desc', 'Freq')]
```

Comment: i just tried that, but with the merge, i got : Error in fix.by(by.x, x) : 'by' must specify a uniquely valid column

Comment: It's hard to tell but it looks like one of your column names is "Procedures" and not "Procedure". In that case you would have to use merge(df2, desc_map, by.x = "Procedure", by.y = "Procedures")

Comment: yeah i already tried that, sorry.  I made sure a bunch of times just now that they were the same.  I got it to run, but it either gives me too little data or too much data.

Comment: too little data usually means that there isn't a Desc map for every Procedure. use all.x = T to fix that.
too much data means that there are more than 1 Desc map for a Procedure. Multiple ways to work around that, but I don't think there's one in the merge function